# Tfrecords error:"Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 71680 values, but the requested shape has 8960"

Tags: python, tensorflow

Those days I get that error when I run the code to read a "tfrecords" data. The question is how to find the 'tensor with 71680 values' or 'shape has 8960'?

The error is:

> ```
> I0807 09:54:11.147000 353860 coordinator.py:224] Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, 2 root error(s) found.
>  (0) Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 71680 values, but the requested shape has 8960
>  [[{{node Reshape}}]]
>  (1) Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 71680 values, but the requested shape has 8960
>  [[{{node Reshape}}]]
>  [[sub/_21]]
>  0 successful operations.
>  0 derived errors ignored.
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
> return fn(*args)
>  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
> options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
>  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
> run_metadata)
>  tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: 2 root error(s) found.
>  (0) Out of range: RandomShuffleQueue '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 4, current size 0)
>  [[{{node shuffle_batch}}]]
>  (1) Out of range: RandomShuffleQueue '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 4, current size 0)
>  [[{{node shuffle_batch}}]]
>  [[CTCLoss/_121]]
>  0 successful operations.
>  0 derived errors ignored.
> ```
>
> The code that I read "tfrecords" data is here:

```
def read_tfrecords():
  ......
  ......
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([tfrecords_path])
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  _,serizalized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(serizalized_example,
                                   features = {
                                       'image_raw':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                       'label': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
                                       })
  images = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'],tf.uint8) # Maybe error is here
  images = tf.cast(images,dtype = tf.float32)
  images = tf.reshape(images, [32, 280, 1])
  labels = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
  images_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([images,labels],batch_size=batch_size,num_threads=1,
                       capacity=5000, min_after_dequeue=1000)
  return images_batch, label_batch
```

I think the key is in `images = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'],tf.uint8)`,but I don't know why and how.Here I give my code to make "tfrecords" data.

```
def write2tfrecords():
....
....
image = cv2.imread(image_path,0)
image = cv2.resize(image, (280, 32))
image = image/255.0-0.5
image_raw = image.tobytes() ## I think the error is here
#image_raw = image.tostring() ## It also don't work
value_label = lable
example = tf.train.Example(features = tf.train.Features(
        feature={
            'image_raw':tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[image_raw])),
            'label':tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value_label]))
        }))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    log.info('Finished image {:s}'.format(key))
writer.close()
```

When I use `PIL.Image` to replace the `cv2`,  It works! Here the image high=32,width=280 .Does someone know why it happened in `cv2`? or how can I read image from `tfrecords` data in right way.

Comment: Please edit this post to include what the  `crnn` looks like.

Comment: Sorry I doesn't get the point of my error. Here I re_write my the place of error in detail

Answer (score 0):

problem is slaved .The problem is here:`image = image/255.0-0.5`.Does someone know why?